# Finding the position of UIPanGestureRecognizer

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have `UIPanGestureRecognizer` added to a view controller. I want to be able to swipe up to go the next view controller (kind of like the camera on the iOS lockscreen).

My problem is I don't know how to find the position of the view being panned.

- If the user passes a certain length and lets go i want to go to the next view controller.
- If the user hasn't reached a certain length and lets go I want the view to go back to its default state before it was panned up.

I know about `locationInView` but i haven't been able to get its work in in my scenario.

I also know that I need use `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` and `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` for all these things, i just don't know how to find the position and set the position. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)panGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGPoint t = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];

        if (t.y < 0) {
            t = CGPointMake(0, t.y);
        }
        else {
            t = CGPointMake(0, t.y);
        }

        //look at this

        recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + t.x, recognizer.view.center.y + t.y);
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];

    }
    else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        //if the view was dragged to past 100 px - go to next view controller, if not go back t the bottom of the screen
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (t.y < 0)` why do you assign the same value ? this condition does not make sense

Answer (score 0):

You life is made harder by resetting the `translationInView` each time the translation changes. You would be better served by storing the default / start position when the gesture begins and setting the new position each time from that default / start position and the combined `translationInView` of the gesture.

In this way you won't get any drift due to calculation errors and you also have the default / start position that you can compare against and reset to, if required, when the gesture ends.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `- (CGPoint)locationInView:(UIView*)view` method on the gesture recognizer.